# Is it possible to find bass peak/highest peak?

Tags: audio, video-processing, moviepy, librosa, pydub

The problem for me is I am trying to find the bass/highest peaks of an audio file. Then I want to find the duration between each peaks. so I can sync my list of video to the duration between peaks. I am using moviepy. And I have tried pydub and librosa, but can't really figure it out

I am trying to sync my a list of videos to the music, by using highest peak

Comment: You mean something like a beat finder? See https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/beat_finder.html maybe you can work out something to call from moviepy?

Comment: Thank you very much @Marcel Indeed this is what I mean, I want to find the peaks and syncronize it to match my clips up. But do you know how I would be able to do it just using python? Or do you know someone who might?

Comment: Can you provide a short example audio clip, and the timestamp (in seconds) for where each peak is? That would make it possible to make a reproducible example

Comment: What is the best way to share the music sample to you? @JonNordby

Comment: Upload using a standard format to a service that allows anonymous access using an URL. For short clips, Google Drive / Dropbox etc works.

Comment: I used google drive, there is a text document generate with librosa of the time stamps and the audio file:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NOnMMltYS7L4dbNPYD2roZL-j0qUffDe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @JonNordby Can this be used?

Comment: @smith yes that looks mostly good. However I note that sometimes the more high frequency percussive hits are marked, and other times not. Can you double-check the timestamps are as you want the output to be? And probably update the question to include the link would be good

Answer (score 0):

librosa provides the tools needed for this, including example code that is a good starting point. See the documentation for [librosa.beat.beat_track](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/generated/librosa.beat.beat_track.html).

For focusing on the bass/low-frequency content you can compute onset strengths separately for the different frequency bands, and pick the lowest one. Librosa provides a very nice function for this in [librosa.onset.onset_strength_multi](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/generated/librosa.onset.onset_strength_multi.html#librosa.onset.onset_strength_multi).

Comment: Yeah I found the example. But awesome to hear about the onset strength, thats really neat, thank you so much.